# timestamp column doesn't update in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I moved an Access database backend to sql server and am still using an Access frontend.  I am now getting overwrite errors when entering records.  I found a solution (thank you) to add a Timestamp (rowversion) column to the table which I did.  However, the timestamp column does not populate for new records nor did it update on the existing records.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please include the `CREATE TABLE`  statement in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timestamp field is for SQL Server's use only. Access neither reads or writes it, but the ODBC driver does.
Its sole purpose is for the ODBC driver to see, before updating a record, if this has changed on the server since the last reading by the driver. If it hasn't, the update is safe - if it has, the record is re-read and the update cancelled.